# How to change style depending on which tab is selected?

Tags: dart, flutter, tabcontrol

Following is my code to handle `TabBar` in `Flutter`

```
TabBar(controller: tabController, indicatorColor: white, tabs: [
        Tab(
          child: Text(
            "Present",
            style: TextStyle(fontFamily: "BarlowBold", color: black),
          ),
        ),
        Tab(
          child: Text(
            "Upcoming",
            style: TextStyle(fontFamily: "BarlowBold", color: black),
          ),
        )
      ]),
```

I need to change the `fontFamily` of text depending on which tab is selected. I tried the properties of `tabController` but they do not help

Comment: Have you imported font in the project? Your code is also looks correct

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Same can be done with - `labelStyle:`  & `unselectedLabelStyle:` of `TabBar`

```
TabBar(
              indicatorColor: Colors.white,
              labelStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 22.0,fontFamily: 'Family Name'),  //For Selected tab
              unselectedLabelStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 10.0,fontFamily: 'Family Name'), //For Un-selected Tabs
              tabs: [
```